# return default if pandas dataframe.loc location doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas

I find myself often having to check whether a column or row exists in a dataframe before trying to reference it. For example I end up adding a lot of code like:

```
if 'mycol' in df.columns and 'myindex' in df.index: x = df.loc[myindex, mycol]
else: x = mydefault
```

Is there any way to do this more nicely? For example on an arbitrary object I can do `x = getattr(anobject, 'id', default)` - is there anything similar to this in pandas? Really any way to achieve what I'm doing more gracefully?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is a method for [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.get.html#pandas.Series.get):

So you could do:

```
df.mycol.get(myIndex, NaN)
```

Example:

```
In [117]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol':arange(5), 'dummy':arange(5)})
df
Out[117]:
   dummy  mycol
0      0      0
1      1      1
2      2      2
3      3      3
4      4      4

[5 rows x 2 columns]
In [118]:

print(df.mycol.get(2, NaN))
print(df.mycol.get(5, NaN))
2
nan
```

Comment: I was also able to get it to work when the index is known to exist:
`df.loc['myindex'].get('mycol', NaN)` A shame that you still need to be sure that one of the index or column exists, but nonetheless this will be useful in a lot of scenarios. Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

Python has this mentality to *ask for forgiveness instead of permission*. You'll find a lot of posts on this matter, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901886/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-it-is-to-get-permission-in-python).

In Python catching exceptions is relatively inexpensive, so you're encouraged to use it. This is called the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach.

For example:

```
try:
    x = df.loc['myindex', 'mycol']
except KeyError:
    x = mydefault
```

Comment: Perhaps I should use more EAFP, but my personal preference is to save try/excepts for when there's no other easy choice. Thanks though.

Comment: @Foobar: according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522005/cost-of-exception-handlers-in-python) it is only the `try:` that is inexpensive. `except:` seems to be expensive. The moral of the story seems to be that the caller is left to decide between testing for existence or `try: except:`ing. The performance trade off depending on your use case. i.e. how long it takes to test existence vs how many times not testing will `raise`. Nevertheless, it would be nice if pandas offered syntactic sugar by permitting that choice to be argument driven. As far as I can tell, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get.html) method for `DataFrame` to get a column and another [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) for `Series` to get an item. So you can chain them together to get a single value:

```
   A  B
0  0  2
1  1  3

df.get('B', default=pd.Series()).get(1, default='[unknown]')
```

Output:

```
3
```

If the index or column is missing:

```
df.get('B', default=pd.Series()).get(2, default='[unknown]')
# or
df.get('C', default=pd.Series()).get(1, default='[unknown]')
```

Output:

```
'[unknown]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reindex`:

```
df.reindex(index=['row1', 'row2'], columns=['col1', 'col2'], fill_value=mydefault)
```

What's great here is using lists for the rows and columns, where some of them exist and some of them don't, and you get the fallback value whenever either the row or column is missing.

Example:

```
In[1]:
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
 'A':[1, 2, 3],
 'B':[5, 3, 7],
})
df

Out[1]:
    A   B
0   1   5
1   2   3
2   3   7

In[2]:
df.reindex(index=[0, 1, 100], columns=['A', 'C'], fill_value='FV')

Out[2]:
    A   C
0   1   FV
1   2   FV
100 FV  FV
```

Comment: Always good to have alternatives, but this would be very slow on a df of any significant size. It creates an entirely new df just to get one value.

Comment: @fantabolous well the point of this is that you can get more than one value, in which case you are creating a new df anyway