# Pandas Dataframe of series, get series by name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of multiple series.  I want to get one series by name, but for the life of me can't figure out how to do it.

Dataframe:

```
         user_id  name    
gender                                                       
male       1      John 
female     2     Abigal
```

I want to get the name of the `male` series. Something like `df['male'].name`

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably read [10 min to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html). `.loc` is fairly fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc['male','name']
```

Comment: That works, I was circling the answer, thank you!! Can I default to 0 is the series with that name doesn't exist?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403352/return-default-if-pandas-dataframe-loc-location-doesnt-exist