# How can I get the keys from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I have a list within a dictionary within a dictionary:

```py
{FirmA:{ProductA:[Color1,Color2,Color3]}}
```

I want to build a list of keys from the First Firm dictionary level.

Then, I need to access the second level Product dictionary based on a Firm Key.

Finally, I will need to access the Colors list based on the Product key from Dictionary level 2 (Products).

I tried to get the level 1 keys for Firms:

```py
[i for i in dict.keys()]
```

Returns

```py
ValueError: Too many values to unpack
```

This is a fairly large data set.

I have not been able to get to the 2nd level dictionary yet.

Comment: @shash678 I updated it in my answer, the actual dictionary I am using is too large.

Comment: Because I am not using the list as a key, only a value.

Comment: If you still need help, please provide a [mcve] that causes the error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
d = {'foo':{'bar':42}}

# you can do much like for nested list, like so:
print(d['foo'])
print(d['foo']['bar'])

# or you can iterate:
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)

    # if the value is also a dictionary, iterate on it again:
    try:
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            if isinstance(v2, list):
                for el in v2:
                    print el
    except:
        pass
```

EDIT: actually if it's a large dataset, and you'll have few values below the first pass actually a dictionary, it may be faster to do an instance check as well (`isinstance(v, dict)`), since catching is expensive. Depends on the details....

Comment: ```for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)``` this works to print, but I need to append these keys to a list.

Then, the next step will be to access the 2nd dictionary using keys from the first dictionary list.

Comment: Just so it's easy to copy-past the whole thing to see/understand the output. Then you do whatever you need with it!

Comment: ```for key, value in d.iteritems():
  li.append(key)``` Returns ```ValueError: Too many values to unpack```

Note: I am on Python 2.7

Comment: It's actually not so clear what you want to do with what. Above you have the syntax you can use to manipulate the dictionnary... either clarify the question or use the above. You do have the tools you need with that to access whatever is needed in your data.

Comment: [Cathing is expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522013/307138)? It might be, depending on the data structure, but that is up to the OP to do some tests ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
def get_products_for_firm(d, firm):
    firm_letter = firm[-1]
    product_prefix = "Product"
    product_key = "%s%s" % (product_prefix, firm_letter)
    return d[firm][product_key]


d = {
    "FirmA": {
        "ProductA": ["Color1", "Color2", "Color3"]
    },
    "FirmB": {
        "ProductB": ["Color4", "Color5", "Color6"]
    }
}

firm_keys = d.keys()
print "The firm keys are %s: " % (firm_keys)

for firm_key in firm_keys:
    print "The products for %s are: %s" % (firm_key,
                                           get_products_for_firm(d, firm_key))
```

**Output:**

```
The firm keys are ['FirmA', 'FirmB']:
The products for FirmA are: ['Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3']
The products for FirmB are: ['Color4', 'Color5', 'Color6']
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `NestedDict` you can extract keys of a nested dictionary as it was flat.

```
from ndicts import NestedDict

d = {"FirmA": {"ProductA": ["red", "blue", "yellow"],
               "ProductB": ["grey", "white"]},
     "FirmB": {"ProductB": ["black"]}}
nd = NestedDict(d)
```

```
>>> keys = list(nd.keys())
>>> keys
[('FirmA', 'ProductA'), ('FirmA', 'ProductB'), ('FirmB', 'ProductB')]
```

If you want to access a specific level use a comprehension

```
>>> 1st_level = [key[0] for key in keys]
>>> 2nd_level = [key[1] for key in keys]
>>> 1st_level, 2nd_level
(['FirmA', 'FirmA', 'FirmB'], ['ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductB'])
```

If you need to access an item:

```
>>> nd["FirmA", "ProductB"]
['grey', 'white']
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`.

Finally, you said that you have a large dataset. While a NestedDict will give you what you want, it is not meant to be performing fast. It is simply meant to give you a simple interface to work with on nested dictionaries. Check out pandas Dataframes to speed up lookups. In particular have a look at MultiIndex, which are great to store hyerarchical data like yours.