# Find which element of list is a key in a dictionary and what is it's value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, processing-efficiency

I have a dictionary:

```
classes_dictionary = {'/m/09x0r': 'Speech', '/m/03qc9zr': 'Screaming'}
```

and a list:

```
labels_list = ['/m/03k3r', '/m/04rlf', '/m/07q5rw0', '/m/09x0r', '/m/0jbk']
```

`labels_list` will always contain at least one element which is a key of `classes_dictionary`. I wish to extract which classes are those with the lowest computational complexity. In this example, `'/m/09x0r'` will be translated into `'Speech'`. my solution:

```
class_str = list()
for k in labels_list:
    print(k)
    if k in self.classes_dictionary:
        class_str.append(self.classes_dictionary[k])
```

I do not mind if the output is a list or any other type. Also, for generality of the question I am assuming only a single element of `labels_list` is a key, though the best answer may consider both cases.

Is there a more efficient way to implement this? I am asking on both, implementation efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [classes_dictionary[k] for k in labels_list if k in classes_dictionary]
['Speech']
```

If only one match is expected, you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression to stop searching once it's found:

```py
>>> next(classes_dictionary[k] for k in labels_list if k in classes_dictionary)
'Speech'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get()` and check if the returned value is not `None` instead of looking if the key exists in the dict (although it's O(1) operation). If you know it's only one value add `break`

```
class_str = []
for k in labels_list:
    value = classes_dictionary.get(k)
    if value:
        class_str.append(value)
```

If you are using Python 3.8 you can use [Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), which will evaluate `classes_dictionary.get(x)` only once

```
class_str = [y for x in labels_list if (y := classes_dictionary.get(x)) is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be for efficent check key on dict.

```
#YOUR CODE
if k in self.classes_dictionary:
    #do_job

#More efficient
try:
    self.classes_dictionary[k]
    #do_job
except:
    #Key not in dict
    pass
```

Comment: This is not more efficient unless the vast majority of the keys are actually present in the dictionary - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522013/12299000): *"try/except is faster than an explicit if as long as the condition is not met. [...] Only if the condition is actually met, then the if version is significantly faster."* According to the OP, only one key is expected to actually be in the dictionary, so this is a case where try/except is significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your labels_list consists of one string. It seems it should be a list of 5 strings. You do not need self. in front of classes_dictionary:

```
class_str = list()
for k in labels_list:
  print(k)
  if k in classes_dictionary:
    class_str.append(classes_dictionary[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `labels_list` is a set instead, you might be able to squeeze out some performance. Use intersection of set and dictionary keys:

```
classes_dictionary = {'/m/09x0r': 'Speech', '/m/03qc9zr': 'Screaming'}
labels_list= set(['/m/03k3r', '/m/04rlf', '/m/07q5rw0', '/m/09x0r', '/m/0jbk'])

[classes_dictionary[k] for k in labels_list & classes_dictionary.keys()]
```

Comment: Testing set membership is the same efficiency as testing dictionary membership, so you can replace the intersection with `if k in classes_dictionary` here.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the intersection of the dict keys with the elements from `labels_list` in a list comprehension:

```
class_str = [classes_dictionary[e] for e in set(classes_dictionary).intersection(labels_list)]
```

**output:**

```
['Speech']
```