# Why does Python try-except cause slowdown?

Tags: python, evdev

I have written a simple application for my RaspberryPi in python3.  My rpi has a fresh install and I have completed all updates prior to starting development.  This application is a sports scoreboard that displays on an LED matrix and utilizes a bluetooth game controller and the evdev module for input controls.

The bluetooth input was working very well, and was 100% responsive except that if it disconnected, the application would crash because it could no longer access /dev/input/event0  (which was is the gamepad input).

I added try-except Exception to the code, which resolved the crash and allowed the code to continue if the gamepad disconnected.  This has introduced two new issues that I need assistance with.

1. About 10% of gamepad input doesn't register now.  Sometimes a button has to be pressed twice to register.
2. Ctl-C in the console will not stop code execution.  I'll get the following in the console:

   KeyboardInterrupt:
   ^CException ignored in: <function InputDevice.**del** at 0x757d6588>

If I remove the try-except for the gamepad read, it will work normally until the gamepad disconnects.  Here is the code in question.

```
while True:
    #Gamepad read
    try:
        dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')    
        gen = dev.read()
    except Exception:
        pass
    #Gamepad functions
    try:
        for ev in gen:
            if ev.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
                if ev.value == 1:
                    if ev.code == 23:
                        if home == 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            home-=1 
                    elif ev.code == 35:
                        home+=1 
                    elif ev.code == 34:
                        away+=1 
                    elif ev.code == 36:
                        if away==0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            away-=1
                    elif ev.code == 49:
                        stopwatch.reset()
                        start_clock == 300
                    elif ev.code == 32:
                        start_clock+=1
                    elif ev.code == 46:
                        start_clock-=1
                    elif ev.code == 33:
                        start_clock+=60
                    elif ev.code == 18:
                        start_clock-=60        
                    elif ev.code == 24:
                        away=00
                        home=00
                    elif ev.code == 37:
                        _draw_ani()
                    elif ev.code == 50:
                        if stopwatch.running:
                            stopwatch.stop()
                        else:
                            stopwatch.start()   
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Comment: Why are you creating the InputDevice object in every iteration?

Comment: `except Exception` is a bad idea, catch the specific error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally checking with `try/except` is costly specially if the exception is raised.[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522005/cost-of-exception-handlers-in-python) is a good reference and can help you in that matter.

I think using `if/else` condition will reduce the load.To do that you should first detect why exception is raised (you can use `except Exception as error` and the analyze the `error` object). Then you can check the condition with `if/else`.

And regarding your code use `with` instead of `opening` and `reading` directly like this:

```
with InputDevice('/dev/input/event0').read() as gen:
    # do stuff with gen obj
```

This way you wouldn't need to close obj manually.
Right now one of the problems in your code is trying to `read` a device while it's open.