Sorting multiple indices of a list according to one of the indices
I'm a Python beginner so I apologise in advance if my question may be obvious.
I have a list called EVENTS that contains lists of information on 'timing','side' and 'labels'. I have recreated a simpler version of the one I am using here:
EVENTS = [ [2.55800009, 1.88999999],['Left', 'Left'], ['Foot Strike', 'Foot Off']]

I would like to sort the list such that the 'timing' is sorted in order of ascence, but so that the strings 'side' and 'label' would follow that order.
so the sorted list should be:
EVENTS_SORTED = [ [1.88999999, 2.55800009],['Left', 'Left'], ['Foot Off', 'Foot Strike']]

I have tried
EVENTS_SORTED = sorted(EVENTS,key=lambda x:(x[0])) 
EVENTS_SORTED = sorted(EVENTS,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

Where I get the error
'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I understand that the approach I am using is thus not applicable to the list I have but I am not entirely sure why.
Any help on a better approach - or a better way to structure the data to make this step easier - would be greatly appreciated

Does this answer your question? sorting multiple lists based on a single list in python

You can use zip to join each item in the sub-lists into groups by their indices.  I.e. zeroth-elements, then index-equal-1-elements, etc.
Then use sorted to sort these groups; the timing is the first element, so it will sort it correctly by default.  Then you can use zip again to push them back to their original groupings.
list(zip(*sorted(zip(*EVENTS))))
# returns:
[(1.88999999, 2.55800009), ('Left', 'Left'), ('Foot Off', 'Foot Strike')]

If you really want them as lists instead of tuples, you can use:
[list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(*EVENTS)))]
# returns:
[[1.88999999, 2.55800009], ['Left', 'Left'], ['Foot Off', 'Foot Strike']]


I would suggest refactoring your code to use some data structures, instead of intermingling data in nested lists. For example
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
import numpy as np

@dataclass
class Event:
  timing: float
  side: np.float64
  labels: str

Then back to your sorting example, this becomes more ergonomic and readable.
EVENTS = [
  Event(2.55800009, 'Left', 'Foot Strike'),
  Event(1.88999999, 'Left', 'Foot Off'),
]

print(sorted(EVENTS, key=lambda e: e.timing))

Output
[
  Event(timing=1.88999999, side='Left', labels='Foot Off'), 
  Event(timing=2.55800009, side='Left', labels='Foot Strike')
]


Thank you for your feedback. I assumed there was a better approach I was missing. However, I now manually recreated this data as an example, but actually the data of 'timing', 'sides' and 'labels' are automatically extracted from an imported file. Thus 'timing' is an array of float64 and 'side' and 'labels' are strings. Is there a similar approach possible in that case?

@IVM What type of "array"?

Yes you can use this general approach, the exact solution just depends on how exactly you are reading from your file (csv.DictReader, numpy.loadtxt, pandas.read_csv, etc). See this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/75610339/2296458

In [111]: events = [ [2.55800009, 1.88999999],['Left', 'Left'], ['Foot Strike', 'Foot Off']]

In [112]: [sorted(events[0])] + [[k[1] for k in sorted(zip(events[0], e), key=operator.itemgetter(0))] for e in events[1:]]
Out[112]: [[1.88999999, 2.55800009], ['Left', 'Left'], ['Foot Off', 'Foot Strike']]

